# Swift Passing specific values in methods as arguments

Tags: ios, methods, parameter-passing, swift4

How can I make method in which a user can pass only specific values for example

```
button.setTitle("SKIP", for: .normal)
```

setTitle method takes specific parameters after "for", we just press . (dot) and it show suggestions for values to pass.

I want to do same thing, for example I want to make a method for calculate distance between 2 points,

```
func distanceBetween(loc1: CLLocation, and loc2: CLLocation, unit: String) -> CLLocationDistance {}
```

here user will pass location1 and location2 as arguments and I want to restrict user when he pass unit, he should have only 3 options, km, miles and meters.

Comment: `enum` is what you need.

Comment: please can you share code snippet that guides me in direction or any tutorial which has example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `enum` with the values you need and use that enum as argument.

```
enum Unit {
     case km
     case miles
     case meters
}
```

Now your function would change to:

```
func distanceBetween(loc1: CLLocation, and loc2: CLLocation, unit: Unit) -> CLLocationDistance {
     switch unit {
     case .km:
         // Do something for kilometers
     case .miles:
         // Do something for miles
     case .meter:
         // Do something for meters
}
```

If in case you add a another unit, your compiler will throw an error saying that you haven't specified a `default` case and you would immediately be made to handle it.

And your fuction call would take any one of the `Unit` as argument. Example:

```
distanceBetween(loc1: location1, and loc2: location2, unit: .km)
```